Integration using u-substitution
What is the integral  $\int4x\sec^2(x^2)\tan^2(x^2)$ ?
Here is what I've done so far,
let $u=x^2$, $dx$=$du/2x$,
$2\int \sec^2(u)\tan^2(u)$,
I used the identity $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$
I then said let $v=\tan^2u$,
I got $2\int v+v^2$,
from this step, I just have to integrate and then replace $v$ and $u$ but I know I am already incorrect.

Recall that $(\tan(u))'=1+\tan^2(u)$, the integral is:
$$2\int \sec^2 u\tan^2 u d u=2\int \tan^2u(1+\tan^2 u) d u=\frac23 \tan^3 u+c=\frac23\tan^3(x^2)+c$$
If you don't see it immediately, let $\tan u=v$, $(1+\tan^2 u)d u=d v$:
$$I=2\int v^2 d v=\frac23v^3+c $$
Now, you have to go back to the $x$ variable:
$$I=\frac23v^3+c=\frac23\tan^3(u)+c=\frac23\tan^3(x^2)+c $$

I completely forgot that $sec^2x$=$tan^2x+1$. Thank you.
